# Google Sheets data validation using hidden lookup value?

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation

Let's say we have a Google Sheet used as a data validation "table"

```
********************************
ID     | Name
********************************
1      | Mike
2      | Sue
3      | Bob
4      | Mike
```

Is there a way to use this table as a data validation aid in other sheets so that the data validation dropdown will show the names, while actually storing the ID?

I am enclosing a [spreadsheet for testing purposes](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fLCq_zbsS5DSn6cihsfo3z-ywBiEzgb7PSZnwj7UtHE/edit#gid=0):

- Data Validation sheet, holds lookup values
- Generic sheets is where the data validations should occur. Column A (hidden) should hold numeric IDs, depending on the value selected from the lookup table, while column B should hold the selected name....

Should handle duplicates in column B (names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drop-down list cell will always show the value you selected, but you can look up the ID in a nearby cell with something like this:

`=iferror( vlookup(D2, { DropdownLists!B2:B, DropdownLists!A2:A }, 2, false) )`

...where `D2` is the drop-down list cell and `DropdownLists!A2:B` is the range where you have the IDs and names.

Alternatively, use an array formula like this:

`=arrayformula( iferror( vlookup(B2:B, { 'Data Validation table'!B2:B, 'Data Validation table'!A2:A }, 2, false) ) )`

This formula will fill the whole column automatically.

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fLCq_zbsS5DSn6cihsfo3z-ywBiEzgb7PSZnwj7UtHE/edit#gid=880583991).

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have edited the OP and attached an editable sheet

Comment: I think I got how your formula works, but what if you have duplicate names?

Comment: If you the same name twice in the list, it will only appear once in the drop-down list. `vlookup()` will return the first ID where the name matches, starting from the top.

Comment: The sample spreadsheet gives "Access denied." See [The correct way to publicly share a Google test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Comment: Done................

Comment: As a final comment, it is impossible to manage a google sheet as a "relational database". Of course a spreadsheet is not a database.......